# Confusion about the conventions for $provide in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand dependency injection in angularjs.  One thing that confuses me, which might just be an exception to a naming convention, is the `$provide` object.

1. In the [angularjs api documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto) it is listed as a `service` of the `auto` module, i.e. it should be injectable into other services, but it is in fact a `provider`, i.e. only injectable into a module's `.config()` block.
2. [As seen here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L615), `$provide` is stored (by default) in the `providerCache`, which makes sense since it is a provider.  However, it does not use use the standard naming convention; that all providers have suffix `Provider`.  That is, it should be named `$provideProvider`.

Is this just a convention of the documentation and an exception to naming convention of `providers`?  Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about the `$provide` service as a service that you can inject during the `.config` section of your module.

```
module.provider('providerName', function() { ... });
module.service('serviceName', function() { ... });
module.factory('factoryName', function() { ... });

// Is the same as:

module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.provider('providerName', function() { ... });
});
module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.service('serviceName', function() { ... });
});
module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('factoryName', function() { ... });
});
```

To answer you questions though:
1. From looking at the source it does not seem that the `$provide` is a typical provider, as it is not registered as a typical provider. This makes sense however due to the fact that `$provide` is used to register *other* providers.
2. I have nothing to base this on but I'm assuming this exception to the naming convention is that this *is* an exception to the rule. The `$provide` service does not work like any of the other providers.